# node modules error: Type parameter 'OT' has a circular constraint

Tags: node.js, angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Getting error while run: `ng serve`

error:

```
Error: node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/effect_creator.d.ts:12:43 - error TS2313: Type parameter 'OT' has a circular constraint.

12 }, DT extends DispatchType<C>, OT extends ObservableType<DT, OT>, R extends EffectResult<OT>>(source: () => R & ConditionallyDisallowActionCreator<DT, R>, config?: C): R & CreateEffectMetadata;
```

how to fix this error?

i tried with

`npm install @ngrx/effects@latest @ngrx/store@latest @ngrx/store-devtools@latest rxjs@latest --save`

but still got error while run `ng serve` in angular project! my angular version is: `^17.1.3` and node vesrion `18.19.0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got exactly the same error, while I worked on the angular update on our project. Finally, it seems like the problem is with the latest Typescript v5.4.2. I just downgraded it to v5.2.2 and it works properly.

I will do a more detailed investigation later, I just would like to let you know to solve your blocker issue right now.

Answer (score 1):

I have also seen this error today after upgrading all angular dependencies in my package.json and thought that it has some connection with NgRx library but then I also lowered typescript version from 5.4.2 to 5.3.3 and error is gone. My package.json looks like this now

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "17.3.0",
"@angular/cdk": "17.3.0",
"@angular/common": "17.3.0",
"@angular/compiler": "17.3.0",
"@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
"@angular/forms": "17.3.0",
"@angular/material": "17.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "17.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "17.3.0",
"@angular/router": "17.3.0",
"@capacitor/android": "5.7.3",
"@capacitor/cli": "5.7.3",
"@capacitor/core": "5.7.3",
"@ionic/angular": "7.8.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "17.1.1",
"@ngrx/store": "17.1.1",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "17.1.1",
"@ngx-translate/core": "15.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "8.0.0",
"chart.js": "4.4.2",
"crypto-js": "4.2.0",
"ngx-device-detector": "7.0.0",
"rxjs": "7.8.1",
"tslib": "2.6.2",
"yarn": "^1.22.22",
"zone.js": "0.14.4"


 },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "17.3.0",
    "@angular/localize": "17.3.0",
    "@cypress/schematic": "2.5.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "latest",
    "@ngrx/eslint-plugin": "17.0.1",
    "@types/crypto-js": "4.2.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "5.1.4",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "20.11.29",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "7.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "7.3.1",
    "chai": "5.1.0",
    "cypress": "13.7.0",
    "eslint": "8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-json-format": "2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "5.1.3",
    "jasmine-core": "5.1.2",
    "karma": "6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "2.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.1.0",
    "mocha": "10.3.0",
    "ng-packagr": "17.3.0",
    "prettier": "3.2.5",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "3.2.4",
    "start-server-and-test": "2.0.3",
    "typescript": "5.3.3",
    "wait-on": "7.2.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try typescript version 5.3.3, I also landed up into the same issue today when trying to upgrade angular to 17.3.0. I noticed some discussion [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/4275) and

1. Downgraded my typescript from 5.4.2 to 5.3.3 in package.json (`"typescript": "5.3.3"`)
2. Reinstalled the packages (`yarn`).

It fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

For me, with Angular 17.3.1, no version of TS 5+ was working. What worked was downgrading ngrx to v15 (15.4.0) and TS to 4.9.5. Also remeber to clear cache before install (not sure if its necessary but wont hurt). Probably not the best idea to go so far beyond supported TS version for Angular 17 (TS >=5.2.0 is recommended for 17) but it works